# Can information encoded with a one time pad be distinguished from random noise?

Tags: encryption, random, cryptography, information-hiding, information-theory

I understand that the cyphertext from a properly used one time pad cypher reveals absolutely no data about the encrypted message.

Does this mean that there is no way to distinguish a message encrypted with a one time pad from completely random noise? Or is there some theoretical way to determine that there is a message, even though you can't learn anything about it?

Comment: Correct - One result of this is that under the UK's version of the patriot act possessing random numbers can get you 5 years in jail

Comment: At the ACM meeting we were assured the law would only be used against 'criminals' - so we didn't need to worry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to determine if a string has been encrypted with a OTP.  You can produce any string of the same size by choosing an appropriate key.

For example (from the [Wikipedia One Time Pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) article), the plaintext "HELLO" can be encrypted with the key "XMCKL", giving ciphertext "EQNVZ".  But it is possible to find keys which produce any 5 character plaintext, such as "LATER".  There is no way to determine the original plaintext without the original key.

A OTP can be 'broken' if it is reused (and therefore is no longer a *one time* pad).  The [Venona Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VENONA_project) is an example of what can happen when OTPs are reused.

A major drawback to OTPs is that you must securely distribute a key equal in size to the plaintext to be encoded.

Answer (score 1):

If your one-time pad is completely random, then anything XOR'd with it also is (assuming your message has no/low correlation with the contents of the one-time pad).

Comment: Of course you could randomly generate a pad of all-0 bits, which would be completely random and have no correlation with the message, but still be distinguished from random noise.

Comment: @Gabe: Seems a little circular. Shouldn't true random number generators generate "noise"? It's incredibly unlikely that you'll get 4096 bits of zeros but much more likely that your random data when XOR'ed with the message will generate an English-readable word/sentence of 512 characters. Even one that makes good sense.

Comment: Andrew: I never said it was likely, just that it could happen!

Comment: Well, wouldn't that be embarrassing.  Your entire message laid bare, because of an anomalous regularity.  It should really make you question what "random" means.  Steven Wolfram hit the nail on the head, IMO, when he gave a concrete definition of randomness, asserting that it cannot be defined without considering issues of perception and analysis. www.wolframscience.com/nksonline/page-552

Comment: When something appears random, what we really mean is that we cannot readily detect any regularities in it.  Regularities imply redundancy, and redundancy implies there's a shorter description of something.  As far as a string of all zeros goes, I see no reason why such a number string should be considered any more or less random than another.  Measures of entropy are just that, a particular (and limited) mode of measurement.  It's really just that our particular mode of perception and analysis (i.e. our ability to find those programs or shorter descriptions of things) which are lacking.